# Springboot 2.5.1 service doesn't stop on System.exit(0)

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

We have a spring-boot service, that needs to stop after it did some DB migration with flyway. We solved that via a callback and the lines

```
int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> 0);
System.exit(exitCode);
```

It worked fine so far (spring-boot 2.4.x), but lately, we went for 2.5.1, and now it doesn't stop anymore. Is this a bug or a feature? Is there another way now to close down the service?

**EDIT**

I did a thread dump, but I'm not so sure how to interpret it

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000027eb000 nid=0x1280 in Object.wait() [0x000000000276d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c29756c8> (a java.lang.Thread)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1252)
    - locked <0x00000006c29756c8> (a java.lang.Thread)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1326)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:107)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:46)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:123)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:170)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:216)
    - locked <0x00000006c28bc680> (a java.lang.Class for java.lang.Shutdown)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:109)
    at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:973)
    at com.whatsoever.glp.moneypenny.config.PostMigrationCallback.supports(PostMigrationCallback.java:44)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.callback.DefaultCallbackExecutor.execute(DefaultCallbackExecutor.java:115)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.callback.DefaultCallbackExecutor.onMigrateOrUndoEvent(DefaultCallbackExecutor.java:73)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:165)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:216)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:165)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:572)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$187/370475881.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    - locked <0x00000006c295db30> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    - locked <0x00000006c2636ae8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.whatsoever.glp.moneypenny.Application.main(Application.java:28)


"RMI TCP Accept-0" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001f040800 nid=0x1554 runnable [0x000000001fcff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x00000006c261d120> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:560)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:528)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:405)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"SpringApplicationShutdownHook" #14 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021126000 nid=0x630 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000022e3f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1021)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000006c2636ae8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.closeAndWait(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook$$Lambda$781/1430717967.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.run(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"RMI TCP Connection(1)-172.19.5.119" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000202bf000 nid=0x594 runnable [0x000000002163e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x00000006c26360a8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:555)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$138/349364571.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #6 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001ec8f800 nid=0x1164 runnable [0x000000001f3be000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x00000006c2641f80> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    - locked <0x00000006c2641f80> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2$1.run(AppMainV2.java:48)


"RMI Scheduler(0)" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000202e0000 nid=0x1ac4 waiting on condition [0x000000002173e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c261cc28> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x000000001d255000 nid=0x2370 in Object.wait() [0x000000001e78f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c2643898> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    - locked <0x00000006c2643898> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)


"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d254000 nid=0x2ae8 in Object.wait() [0x000000001e68f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c261d9d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000006c261d9d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)


"Service Thread" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001ecf3000 nid=0x28a4 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


"C1 CompilerThread3" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001ece4800 nid=0x24e4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


"C2 CompilerThread2" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001ed29000 nid=0x27dc waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


"C2 CompilerThread1" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001ed28000 nid=0x3170 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


"C2 CompilerThread0" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001ed1f800 nid=0x4108 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d263000 nid=0x2980 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d262000 nid=0x2144 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d250800 nid=0x4568 runnable 


"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000283e000 nid=0x1254 runnable 


"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000283f800 nid=0x4490 runnable 


"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002841000 nid=0x28b0 runnable 


"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002842800 nid=0x325c runnable 


"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002846000 nid=0x1a18 runnable 


"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002847000 nid=0x35c0 runnable 


"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000284a800 nid=0xdfc runnable 


"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000284b800 nid=0x2fc0 runnable 


"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001f04c000 nid=0x492c waiting on condition 
JNI global references: 1665
```

I guess it is about this *waiting to lock <0x00000006c28ae9a0>*, but I'm not sure

**EDIT 2**

Here are the relevant classes involved

Callback used to shutdown the service after migration was done

```
@Component
public class PostMigrationCallback implements Callback {

  private final FlywayCustomProperties flywayCustomProperties;
  private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  public PostMigrationCallback(FlywayCustomProperties flywayCustomProperties, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.flywayCustomProperties = flywayCustomProperties;
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Event event, Context context) {
    if (event.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("afterMigrate") && flywayCustomProperties.isMigrationOnly()) {
      log.info("Service is going to shutdown as configuration was set to spring.flyway.migrate-only=true and schema was migrated successfully");
      int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> 0);
      System.exit(exitCode);
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean canHandleInTransaction(Event event, Context context) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void handle(Event event, Context context) {
  }

  @Override
  public String getCallbackName() {
    return "MigrationOnlyCallback";
  }
}
```

Factory configuring the callback

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    value = "spring.flyway.enabled",
    havingValue = "true"
)
public class FlywayFactory {

  private PostMigrationCallback postMigrationCallback;

  public FlywayFactory(PostMigrationCallback postMigrationCallback) {
    this.postMigrationCallback = postMigrationCallback;
  }

  @Bean
  public FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway) {
    Flyway flywayWithCallback = Flyway.configure().configuration(flyway.getConfiguration()).callbacks(flywayCallback()).load();
    return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flywayWithCallback);
  }

  @Bean
  public Callback flywayCallback() {
    return postMigrationCallback;
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like closing the application context has left one or more non-daemon threads running which will prevent the JVM from exiting. A thread dump will show what those threads are and hopefully indicate a possible cause.

Comment: It looks like another thread is still in the middle of closing the application context. Can you share the complete thread dump?

Comment: I put the whole thing I exported via Intellij in there

Comment: I was a bit hasty in posting my (now deleted) answer. I see the same behaviour with Spring Boot 2.4.x which means I don't understand your problem as you said things worked fine for you in 2.4.x. Can you please comment on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27049 or update your question here with a minimal sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I added the relevant classes; the factory and the callback. Nevertheless, we added the config spring.main.register-shutdown-hook=false that you proposed as a workaround and it solved the issue for us.

Comment: Thanks. I've reproduced the difference in behaviour now. I've reinstated my answer and added an alternative approach to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for the thread dump. The problem's caused by [a possible bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27049) in Spring Boot where it deadlocks when `System.exit(int)` is called while the application context is being refreshed. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Until the problem is fixed in Spring Boot you can work around it by setting `spring.main.register-shutdown-hook` to `false`.

As [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.1/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.application-exit), `SpringApplication.exit` is intended for use in your application's `main` method. Your usage of it is rather unusual and you may want to explore taking a different approach.

It looks like you want your application to run in a mode when it migrates the database and then shuts down. Your current approach doesn't appear to restrict what may happen up until the point that the database is migrated. You could take a little more control over that by using a different main `@Configuration` class when starting your application. Something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("migrate")) {
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(DatabaseMigration.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
        }
        else {
            SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
        }
    }

    @ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = { FlywayAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
    static class DatabaseMigration {

    }

}
```

The above, when started with a `--migrate` command line argument, will do just enough to create a `DataSource`, run Flyway, and then exit.

Comment: Many thanks for your support and also for your hint regarding the alternative way of starting the migration. I need to check if I can handle it like that as the real setup in our case is a little bit more complex as we pack all our spring-boot services in a container image based on a template. So I'm a little limited here if don't want to change our ci templates. Nevertheless, I'll check if there is another way.

Comment: Maybe a follow up. I just checked the docu link and you are right in the code sample, SpringApplication.exit is called in the main, but there is no indication that this should/needs to be like that. I would have interpreted it as the smallest possible example to demonstrate how to use it, but without limitation to use it anywhere else.